# Find out if segment is fully inside of polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry

How can I find out if a segment starting at a point A on the border of P and ending at a point B on the border of P is fully contained inside of P?

Edit: Let it be that in this case it is not necessary to check for intersections of the segment with other segments on the border of the polygon, as it will be done later on.

Can this be done in constant time?

Comment: I edited the description, there are some limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the edited description, assume that the polygon is simple, that it is represented as a list of segments in counterclockwise sorted order, that the interior of the query segment does not intersect the boundary of the polygon, and that, for either endpoint of the query segment, we know which polygon segment or segments contain that endpoint.

If the endpoint is a polygon vertex, then there are two possible situations. These are distinguishable in constant time by comparing the angles relative to the vertex with a 2D determinant test.

```
Case 1: segment not in polygon

        \ query segment
         \
*<--------*<--------*
  polygon
  interior


Case 2: segment in polygon

*<--------*<--------*
  polygon  \
  interior  \ query segment
```

If the endpoint lies in the interior of a polygon segment, then there's an analogous test (pretend that there's a vertex there).

Here are the details of the angle test. Translate everything so that the polygon vertex is at `(0,0)`. Then we have

```
(e,f)     (0,0)     (c,d)
  *<--------*<--------*
    polygon  \
    interior  \ query segment
               *
             (a,b)
```

Rotate (and scale, not that it matters) everything so that the query segment lies on the x-axis. This is accomplished by multiplying by the matrix

```
[ a b]
[-b a]
```

to obtain the new diagram

```
        * (ac+bd,ad-bc) = (p,q)
       /
      /
    |_     query
    *-----------* (a^2+b^2,0)
   /
  /
|_
* (ae+bf,af-be) = (r,s).
```

By our degeneracy assumptions, `(p,q) != (0,0)`. Now, `(p,q)` is in the upper half-plane if `q>0 || (q==0 && p>0)`. Otherwise, it's in the lower half-plane. Similarly for `(r,s)`.

If `(p,q)` is in the upper half-plane and `(r,s)` is in the lower, then the query segment is inside. If vice versa, then it's outside. Otherwise, the points are in the same half-plane. The determinant test is whether `ps-qr > 0` (inside) or `ps-qr < 0` (outside). It cannot be equal because the polygon is simple.

Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can reduce the degree of this test from quartic.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean with: Comparing the angles relative to the vertex with a 2D determinant test?

Comment: Which angles should be compared?

Comment: @Geminus Added details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sure if I understand entirely: I have to always rotate it that way, that the direction of (p,q) to (0,0) and (0,0) to (r,s) is "downwards"? Also does (0,0) describe the start or the end of the query segment?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how this works if i for example have a "horseshoe" and my query segment goes from left to right in the outside of the inner side of the horseshoe, so the query segment is not inside of the horseshoe.

Comment: @Geminus If the outer boundary of the horseshoe is oriented right-to-left, then the inner boundary of the horseshoe is oriented left-to-right, so it's fine. Mathematically, there exists a [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) from whatever polygon you dream up to something convex, which preserves the local angles (all we care about for the test).

Comment: Again thanks a lot. As a last question if you have some time: Could you elaborate a bit why this approach is always correct?

Comment: @Geminus Simplifying wildly, a simple polygon has the property that, when you follow the boundary counterclockwise, the neighborhood to the left is always inside, and the neighborhood to the right is always outside. Since the query segment does not cross the polygon, its interior either is completely inside or completely outside, so we can determine the status of the whole segment from points arbitrarily close to the endpoint. Then it's just a matter of looking at a sufficiently small disk around the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to distinguish between the following two cases:

- AB is entirely within the polygon
- except for endpoints, AB is entirely outside the polygon

We have ruled out the case where AB is partially inside the polygon, since you've already tested whether AB intersects with each side.

It seems to me, then, that your question is equivalent to asking whether the midpoint of AB is contained within the polygon. Wikipedia has a decent article describing how to determine this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. I would suggest the winding number approach if you want things to be numerically stable.